# Verify web service is available

Tags: c++, linux, wsdl

I have a C++ program that will be retrieving a url which specifies a wsdl.  My program is simply middleware and doesn't perform any wsdl related requests; it will literally read the data and pass it on to whomever will use the url.

That being said, within Linux, can I test to see if the webservice is available within my code?  A sort of a wsdl ping would be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can you not just use any standard Internet browser(chrome,safari,firfox etc) to send the request to the Webserver? If the requests succeeds, the webservice is available, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use curl, ping the url, and check the response code. Look [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html) for a bunch of libcurl examples

Answer (score 1):

Just HTTP GET the WSDL.  Or HEAD it.

If you use libcurl, [here's the docs for it](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-easy.html)

Comment: Would that be a system call, HTTP GET?

Comment: libcurl has a C api -- add it to your link line, and include the header in your .cpp files.  You call curl_easy_setopt() and curl_easy_perform().  It's in the docs I linked to.

Comment: If you want to assume that wget or curl are installed on the system, then you could make a system call to either of them.  You can find out command-line options in man.